# Linking to resource member routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :user do
  post 'profile', :on => :member
end
```

I'm trying to link to a specific user's profile. `app.user_path(@user)` gives me `users/12443`, but I need `users/12443/profile`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
app.user_profile_path(@user)
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method :(

Comment: @Cev, Could you post the output of running `rake routes`?

Comment: Didn't even think of checking routes. It was app.profile_user_path(@user). Thanks!